# NUnit: Unit Testing Entity Framework ViewModel in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm just getting started with the absolute basics of unit testing. I've used a beginners tutorial [Nunit Beginners guide](http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/a-beginner-tutorial-on-writing-unit.html) as a guide.

Here's my test ViewModel which has one method which performs a linq query with EF. The Class is in the same project as my application for now.

```
namespace diiEntitlements.Tests
{
  [TestFixture]

   public class EntitlementsViewModelTests : NotifyPropertyBase
   {      
       EntitlementEntities _context = new EntitlementEntities();

       private ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader> _accountHeaderCollection;
       public ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader> AccountHeaderCollection
       {
           get { return _accountHeaderCollection; }
           set
           {
               _accountHeaderCollection = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("AccountHeaderCollection");
           }
       }

    [Test]
    public void GetAccountHeaders()
    {
        var query = from a in _context.vwAccountHeaders
                    select a;

        AccountHeaderCollection = new ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader>(query);
    }
}
```

When I run the test in NUnit I get the following exception:

"*No connection string named 'EntitlementEntities' could be found in the application config file*"

Now presumably this is because the `.nunit` test file can't access the `app.config` connection string within the project?

Is there a work around for this & is this even the best approach or should I look into mocking the db for testing?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you don't have the connection string into the unit testing project.

As for mocking, it depends on what you want; usually, on unit testing, you only test the business code and you mock the integration points(database, web services and so on). If you need to test the whole flow, from presentation layer to database, then you have integration testing, and you don't need Mock.

Hope this helps.